# Checking collision only during animations

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, collision

I have this knight character with a sword and an attacking animation. I want to check if the sword is colliding with an enemy and then decrease the enemy health. I managed to do that but EVERY TIME the sowrd's collider hits the enemy's collider I have the interaction. Obviously I don't want that, but the interaction should happen ONLY when the player is attacking.
I tried different approahces:

- Check the attack with a boolean, by doing this in the character script

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("hit1", true);
            isAttacking = true;
        }
```

and this in the enemy script

```
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Sword") && knight.isAttacking)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit");

            currentHealth -= 10;
            Debug.Log("Enemy healh: " + currentHealth.ToString());

            healthBar.UpdateHealthBar();
        }
```

- Check if the animation is running using `animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("nameOfTheAnimationState")` instead of `knight.isAttacking`

Nothing seems to work so far, I know that I'm missing something stupid and I'm going to facepalm when you guys will tell me so, please, make me facepalm!
Thanks.

Comment: Do you switch the boolean `isAttacking` to false after the attack?

Comment: I switch it back to false in an else statement, right after the if statement, like this:
`else { GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("hit1", false); isAttacking= false; }`

Answer (score 0):

In the animation window, open the attack animation of the player which roughly looks like this

[image]

---

Now, try playing with the vertical white bar, moving it shows the animation snapshot of the player at each keyframe. Now, find the keyframe at which the player lifts the sword to hit the enemy. Add an event there by clicking the button that's circled red in the image below

[image]

---

After adding the event, you'll see the function in the inspector that's invoked by the event when the animation reaches that keyframe.

[image]

---

Now, create a function to set the attack point `active` in your script.

[image]

---

Find the keyframe at which the player drops the sword after hitting the enemy and add an event there. Invoke another function that sets the attack point to `false`.

[image]

Comment: You can directly enable/disable colliders in the animation frames too, drag the collider onto the left-side of the animation. Also, it allows you to animate the size/shape of the collider during animation.